# Wordpress Elementor : MySQL "command out of sync error" when I click on update

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am using Elementor plugin in Wordpress. I have designed a layout and when i click on update in order to save the layput, it throws Server 500 error.
On looking at the error response, it shows the following response :

```
WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wpseo_sitemap_1_cache_validator' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wpseo_sitemap_1_cache_validator', '2Z2AY', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wpseo_sitemap_1_cache_validator', '2Z2AY', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '\_transient\_yst\_sm\_1\_%' OR option_name LIKE '\_transient\_timeout\_yst\_sm\_1\_%'

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'wpseo_sitemap_page_cache_validator' LIMIT 1

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wpseo_sitemap_page_cache_validator', '2Z2AY', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('wpseo_sitemap_page_cache_validator', '2Z2AY', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)

WordPress database error: [Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now]
DELETE FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '\_transient\_yst\_sm\_page\_%' OR option_name LIKE '\_transient\_timeout\_yst\_sm\_page\_%'
```

Is there a possible way to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show the associated code.

Comment: The page is made using the Elementor plugin, using drag and drop of UI elements. So I don't have any associated code for this.